# ComboBox Reset to Select the Text of the ComboBox in windows Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I had added the items 
1
2
3 to the combobox.

Then I gave the "Select" to the text of the combobox.

How can I able to reset combobox to select the text("Select").

I had tried by giving -1 to the SelectedIndex. But it gives only Empty.

This is for VB.NET Windows Application

I have given an Image for your reference

Image path for the reference 
http://www.drivehq.com/file/df.aspx/publish/rk.babu/Files/ComboBoxReset.jpg

Answer (score 2):

If the ComboBox1 property 'DropDownStyle' is set to 'Simple' or 'DropDown' then

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then ComboBox1.Text = "Select"
End Sub
```

will work. If set to 'DropDownList' then not...

Comment: Thank you for effective answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set 0 value to SelectedIndex property. It will select 1st list item.

```
private Sub button1_Click(sender as object,e as  EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry this if for vb.net windows application project

Comment: I have given image for your reference

http://www.drivehq.com/file/df.aspx/publish/rk.babu/Files/ComboBoxReset.jpg

Comment: First item of list collection must be "Select".

Answer (score 1):

Just set the text property:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then ComboBox1.Text = "Select"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

combobox1.Text = "Select"

and change the attribute of the combobox dropdownstyle to dropdown

Answer (score 1):

for combobox1 dropdown list i use

```
combobox1.ResetText()
combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1
```

works here .

Answer (score -1):

double click the clear button in the design screen and type the following code to clear the value that is selected in the combo box.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        c1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: The OP explicitly says "I had tried by giving -1 to the SelectedIndex. But it gives only Empty."